# Linear in/dependency of $S=\{\{1,1,a\} , \{a,-1,a^2\},\{1,-a,0\}\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors, systems-of-equations

I need help with the following question:

Given is the set $S$ which has $3$ vectors $\in$ $\mathbb R^3$: $S=\{\{1,1,a\} , \{a,-1,a^2\},\{1,-a,0\}\}$

1. For which values of $a$ is $S$ linearly independent?
2. In the cases for which $S$ is linearly dependent, "complete" it such that $S$ is a spanning set of $\mathbb R^3$.
3. For which values of $a$ is the vector $v=\{a,-a^2,a^2-1\}$ a linear combination of $S$?

---

To decide upon linear in/dependency, I first obtain the row echelon form (REF) of the suitable augmented matrix:

$$\left[ 
    \begin{array}{ccc|c}
        1 & a & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & -a-1 & -a-1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & -a & 0 \\
    \end{array}
\right]$$

From it I can deduce $3$ different cases with $t$ being a parameter:

Case 1: $a=0$, from which follows the general solution $(-t,-t,t)$

Case 2: $a=-1$, from which follows the general solution $(t,t,0)$

Case 3: $a \neq 0,-1$, from which no solution follows except the trivial solution $(0,0,0)$

So, to my understanding, the answer to $1$ is just case 3: $a \neq 0,-1$. Does this mean that for cases 1 and 2, when $a=0,-1$, then $S$ is necessarily linearly dependent? But it makes no sense to me, because I've learnt that a linearly dependent set of vectors in $\mathbb F^n$ must contain $k>n$ vectors. And here in $\mathbb R^3$ I have $k=3=n$ vectors only. However, the first 2 cases can neither be linearly independent, because any $t \neq 0$ creates a non-trivial solution. **What is the flaw in my understanding of this topic?**

**As for part 2**, I don't know how to approach this, I don't know if I understand it correctly. Logically, it seems to me that any vector which isn't a linear combination of $S$ would suffice.

**And for part 3**, I obtain the following REF:

$$\left[ 
    \begin{array}{ccc|c}
        1 & a & 1 & a \\
        0 & -a-1 & -a-1 & -a^2-a \\
        0 & 0 & -a & -1 \\
    \end{array}
\right]$$

And even after splitting this into several cases, namely $a=-1$ and $a \neq -1$ I get that every value of $a$ can result in $v$ being a linear combination of $S$, which is weird, and I assume it is wrong. Would appreciate an answer addressing as many points as possible that I am struggling with. Thanks!

Comment: For the $a=-1$ case the first two columns will be scalar multiples of each other, therefore it is linearly dependent.

Comment: The flaw in your understanding lies in the line "I've learnt that a linearly dependent set of vectors in $\mathcal{F}^n$ must contain $k\gt n$ vectors." You've got that implication going the wrong way; any set of $k\gt n$ vectors in an $n$-dimensional vector space must be linearly independent, but one can have linear dependence in any number of dimensions with as few as two vectors — consider $\langle 1, 0, 0, \ldots\rangle$ and $\langle 2, 0, 0, \ldots\rangle$.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki actually, already with one single vector - consider $\langle 0,\ldots,0\rangle$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I was thinking about that, in fact, but the zero vector is a little bit of a corner case for many things, so...

Comment: So, a set of $k>n$ vectors is necessarily dependent, but a dependent set may contain $k \leq n$ vectors? So this is not an "iff" condition, right? @StevenStadnicki

Comment: Exactly that, yes. (And showing that a set of $\gt n$ vectors must be dependent can make for a nice problem.)